# Windows folder search

Tags: windows-xp, search

I am on Windows-XP Professional. While using the windows search to find a keyword or phrase in file, is there any option to say that return results having that world only, do not return if that word is part of a other big word.

e.g. I want to search all files having keyword "link"

but I do not want the results to show me files which have the word "unlink" where "link" is a part of "unlink"

I could not find any options for even in the advanced search options. It did have one Case Sensitive , but no option to say something like "match whole word only" .

What are my other options, if not Windows native search?

Does google desktop search tool has this option to find whole word only?

Comment: I don't even think the Google Desktop Search Tool is still supported.  I suggest Windows Search 4.0 since its geared specifically towards Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Windows Search 4. See [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711.aspx)

"match whole word only" query

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query="WindowsS"
```

[image: "match whole word only" query]

Wildcard Prefix

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query="WindowsS"*
```

[image: Wildcard Prefix query WDS 4]

Type of content

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query="WindowsS"* kind:docs
```

[image]

Wildcard suffix

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query=*ation
```

[image: Wildcard suffix WDS 4]

Parenthesized query

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query=((fibonacci)OR(simplex))kind:docs
```

[image: Parenthesized query WDS 4]

Far manager 2, command line WDS 4.

[image: Far manager 2 command line WDS 4]

Extensions file types:

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query="unsigned short" ext:.h
```

Additional. After indexing 400k+ content files search query time ...

Need good query!

Size base of Windows.edb 1794Mb. Size folder Search 3135 Mb.

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query=((ext:.h)OR(ext:.cpp)OR(ext:.c)) "unsigned short"
```

[image: Extensions file types]

```
WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query=folder:("N:\Exchange\"*) ((ext:.h)OR(ext:.cpp)OR(ext:.c)) "unsigned short"
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what option/switch is used to search a keyword only in *.c , *.cpp *.h files.

Comment: WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query=((ext:.h)OR(ext:.cpp)OR(ext:.c)) "unsigned short"

Comment: WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query=folder:("N:\Exchange\") ((ext:.h)OR(ext:.cpp)OR(ext:.c)) "unsigned short"