# Is there a way to create an Outlook search folder from a search?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I often do mail searches in Outlook and then wish that there were a way to save the search criteria to re-run later. Ideally, there would be a button on the Search tab that would allow me to create a Search Folder from my search criteria. I don't see a way to do this from within Outlook 2010 (although the "Recent Searches" drop-down is helpful for a limited number of recent searches). Are there any plugins for Outlook that would enable this functionality for Outlook 2010, or is there a chance that this functionality is included in Outlook 2013?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/547541/windows-folder-search `WindowsSearch.exe /url search-ms:query="need" kind:email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [this functionality was available in Outlook 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/back-up-or-recreate-a-search-folder-HA001096303.aspx) and 2007 from the Advanced Find dialog but was [removed in Outlook 2010](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/outlook-2010-how-to-create-search-folder-using-query-builder/) and 2013.  Unfortunately, it seems that you have to create search folders "manually" in 2010 and 2013.  Unless someone knows of an add-on or App for Office 2013 that will do this?